# Javafx List<> and ObservableList

Tags: javafx

I have the following:

```
List<Cars>listview=new ArrayList<Cars>();

ObservableList<Cars>data=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

How I can set observable list with `List<Car>`?

Because I want to make class of `List<Car>listview` and get all items from it for use in Observable list (for show sql server information in table).

Comment: please read the api doc of classes you are using ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FXCollections.observableList(listview);
```

or

```
FXCollections.observableArrayList(listview);
```

In both cases, you should no longer modify the list using the original `listview`.

The difference of these two is that the first method creates an observable list that updates the original list, while the second method creates an observable list that starts with the elements in `listview`, but these two lists are unrelated after that.

Comment: thank you very much for answer. then i can set elements in listview and get elements like that? List<elements>listview=new ArrayList<elements>();

Comment: public class CarDao {
    
   private ObservableList<Cars>data=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   
   public void list(Cars car){
   List<Cars>listview=new ArrayList<Cars>();
   data.addAll(listview);
   
   }}
I wrote this code. it can be work?

Comment: @MehmanHummetli What would you expect that code to do? You create an observable list (`data`), which is initially empty. Then you create a regular list (`listview`), which is also initially empty. Then you add all the elements of `listview` (there are none, because it's empty) to `data`. What is the purpose of this code?